# Set a variable in pipeline to use in bicep

Tags: azure-devops, azure-bicep

i am using a release pipeline to create my resources in Azure. I have a DBConnection-string parameter to set on a created/updated KeyVault secret, but i do not like the idea of having it in plain text in my parameter file.

I have created a variable group in Pipelines/Library, and I have added this group to the pipeline variables.

But i cannot seem to reference it in either the BICEP or in the parameters file.

In bicep:

```
param DBConnection string
```

In parameters.json:

```
..
  "parameters": {
 "DBConnection": {
      "value":"I want this to come from pipeline variables"
    },
```

How would I be able to do this?

I have tried stuff like:

```
"value": "$(DBConnection)"
```

But this just writes "$(DBConnection)" in the secret

UPDATE:
using

```
-DBConnection "$(DBConnection)"
```

in Override template parameters did the trick.

NOTE: Spent hours debugging why

```
-DBConnection $(DBConnection)
```

didn't work. Turns out any spaces in the values will break it and cause an empty-variable error

Comment: Can you share the step in your Azure Pipeline where you launch the bicep deployment?

Comment: If you are using bicep another method would be to have bicep use the ['existing'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource) property and [getSecrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#use-getsecret-function) function to pull the value from Key Vault assuming the ADO principle has Key Vault access. If it fits can provide an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is not to put it in the parameters file, but pass the parameter at the point of deployment.

This pattern can also be used to override values in the parameters file.

eg.

```bash
az deployment group create -g YourRG -f main.bicep -p params.json -p DBConnection=$(DBConnection)
```

If you're using the Azure DevOps pipeline task for [AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines#syntax) then you'd use `overrideParameters`.

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(azureServiceConnection)'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(resourceGroupName)'
    location: '$(location)'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(templateFile)'
    overrideParameters: '-DBConnection $(DBConnection)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    deploymentName: 'DeployPipelineTemplate'
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped me get the variable into the generated YAML :-)

Answer (score 0):

Decided to just provide the code to do this in [Bicep natively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#use-getsecret-function).  :

```
param sqlServerName string
param adminLogin string

param subscriptionId string
param kvResourceGroup string
param kvName string

resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: kvName
  scope: resourceGroup(subscriptionId, kvResourceGroup )
}

module sql './sql.bicep' = {
  name: 'deploySQL'
  params: {
    sqlServerName: sqlServerName
    adminLogin: adminLogin
    adminPassword: kv.getSecret('vmAdminPassword')
  }
}
```

sql.bicep module:

```
param sqlServerName string
param adminLogin string

@secure()
param adminPassword string

resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2020-11-01-preview' = {
  name: sqlServerName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: adminLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: adminPassword
    version: '12.0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use KeyVault reference inside your parameter file;

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "DBConnection": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault-name>"
        },
        "secretName": "MyAppDBConnection"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-static-id