# Pass azure devops pipeline variable to Linux OS level via bicep

Tags: linux, bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, rhel

EDIT: To clarify: The variable is empty **within the Linux box**. The pipeline variable works as intended.

I need to pass a GUI pipeline variable - $USER1 to a Linux box deployed in the same pipeline in bicep. Tried the custom script extension but the variable $pat1 is empty in the shell.
How can I pass the variable ?

```
resource customScriptExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-07-01' = {

  parent: virtualMachine
  name: 'config-app-linux'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions'
    type: 'CustomScript'
    typeHandlerVersion: '2.1'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      skipDos2Unix: false
      timestamp: 123456789
    }
    protectedSettings: { 
      commandtoExecute: 'pat1="$USER1"'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "GUI pipeline variable"?

Comment: You can define [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameters) in your bicep, and override the parameters in DevOps task `ARM template deployment`. Or override the parameter in azure cli. Please refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76532394/14996050) for your reference.

Comment: @VladDX Var set in the Pipeline GUI: Edit Pipeline > Variables

Comment: @Hanscastor, may i know if you checked the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532136/set-a-variable-in-pipeline-to-use-in-bicep) shared above? It has the same query. Need to use parameter not variable in bicep file.

Comment: @Hanscastor, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT it solves the wrong problem. The problem is not that the var is empty in the pipeline. It's empty when I want to use it in the script run via the extension on the Linux os itself.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goals, I think three parts need to work together to complete

1. **part 1:** sample.bicep

   ```
   param USER1 string

   var commandtoExecute = 'pat1=${USER1}'

   resource customScriptExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2023-07-01' = {

     parent: virtualMachine
     name: 'config-app-linux'
     location: location
     properties: {
       publisher: 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions'
       type: 'CustomScript'
       typeHandlerVersion: '2.1'
       autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
       settings: {
         skipDos2Unix: false
         timestamp: 123456789
       }
       protectedSettings: { 
         commandtoExecute: commandtoExecute
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. **part 2:** a deploy file to run the bicep named deploy.ps1

   ```
   param (
       [string]$USER1
   )
   New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -TemplateFile "sample.bicep" -USER1 $USER1
   ```
3. **part 3**: a yaml file to define the pipeline to run named pipeline.yml

   ```
   parameters:
   - name: USER1
     type: string

   steps:
   - task: AzurePowerShell@5
     inputs:
       azureSubscription: XXX
       ScriptType: FilePath
       ScriptPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\deploy.ps1
       scriptArguments:
         -USER1 ${{ parameters.USER1 }}
       azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
   ```

you should passout the parameters or variables from bicep to yaml with the bridge of a deploy script.

> above process is just an example, you may need do lots of detail modification.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is, that the variable is empty within the Linux box. The pipeline variable has the correct content.